# MVC and Automapper multiple level of nesting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper

I am starting off with MVC and auto mapper and would appreciate some guidance.I have some domain models and a view model which is a combination of these domain models. Basically there are 4 classes

`Transcription` has an associated `Audio` which is owned by a `Client Staff` who has a userid in `Users`

Database relationship diagram:

http://i49.tinypic.com/whcwsz.jpg

Domain models EF generated (Only relevant fields)

```cs
public class audio
{
    public int AudioID { get; set; }
    public string AudioLength { get; set; }
    public virtual ClientStaff ClientStaff { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Transcription> Transcriptions { get; set; }
}

public class ClientStaff
{
    public int ClientStaffID { get; set; }
    public int StaffType { get; set; }
    public int ClientID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Audio> Audios { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }    
    public virtual ICollection<ClientStaff> ClientStaffs { get; set; }
}

public class Transcription
{
    public int TranscriptionID { get; set; }
    public string TranscriptionText { get; set; }
    public virtual Audio Audio { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> AudioID { get; set; }
}
```

View model

```cs
public class customVM
{
    public int AudioID { get; set; }//get from audio
    public string Path { get; set; }//get from audio
    public string AudioLength { get; set; }//get from audio
    public DateTime AudioCreatedOn { get; set; }//get from audio
    public int ClientStaffID { get; set; }//get from audio
    public string TranscriptionText { get; set; }//get from transcription
    public DateTime TranscriptionCreatedOn { get; set; }//get from transcription
    public string UsersFirstName { get; set; }//get from users
    public string UsersLastName { get; set; }//get from users 
}
```

Controller action

```cs
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IEnumerable<Audio> x= db.getAudioFiles();
    Mapper.CreateMap<Audio, customVM>();
    IEnumerable<customVM> model =
        Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Audio>, IEnumerable<customVM>>(x);
    Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

    return View(model);
}
```

The problem :

`AutoMapper` is picking up properties from `Transcription` and `ClientStaff` but how do I get the user first names and last names? Or rather to generalise how do I get a 2nd level nested class properties with auto mapper. Or am I approaching the whole issue incorrectly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to define it explicitly. For example:

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<Audio, customVM>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.UsersFirstName,
               opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ClientStaff.User.FirstName))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.UsersLastName,
               opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ClientStaff.User.LastName));
```

Also I believe that you don't need to specify `IEnumerable` in your map, although I haven't tested that. Ie, I've been told that this should work:

```cs
IEnumerable<customVM> model= Mapper.Map<Audio, customVM>(x);
```

Its not overly important, but does clean up the code a little.

As an aside, instead of having the mapping configuration in your action, you should only configure the mapping once. The best way to do this is by using profiles:

```cs
public class MyProfile : Profile
{
    public override string ProfileName
    {
        get
        {
            return "MyProfile";
        }
    }

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Audio, customVM>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.UsersFirstName,
                       opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ClientStaff.User.FirstName))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.UsersLastName,
                       opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ClientStaff.User.LastName));
    }
}
```

This should then be initialised in an initialisation method (such as `App_Start` for web projects)

You should also create a unit test to test the mapping has been configured correctly

```cs
[TestFixture]
public class MappingTests
{
    [Test]
    public void AutoMapper_Configuration_IsValid()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(m => m.AddProfile<MyProfile>());
        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    }
}
```

Your controller action would then be:

```cs
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IEnumerable<Audio> x= db.getAudioFiles();
    IEnumerable<customVM> model =
        Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Audio>, IEnumerable<customVM>>(x);
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Absolute legend!! Thanks for such a clear concise explanation.  Mapper.Map<Audio, customVM>(x) throws an invalid argument however so dont think that will work.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I was challenged about that once, and was curious to know if it worked, but haven't had the chance to try it yet.

Comment: Note that for safety, you might want to specify your mapping something like this: `src => (src.ClientStaff == null || src.ClientStaff.User == null) ? string.Empty : src.ClientStaff.User.FirstName`